# how to expand page to full screen

Tags: html, css

I have a page with elements but i need to expant it to full. So. i have tried to make it, but when i'm do it, size of page becomes a fixed. how to fix it? 
Examples:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}

.main-body{
    height: 100%;
    background: deepskyblue;
    bottom: 0;
}

.main-line{
    height: 95%;
    background: aliceblue;
}
.footer{
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

so, with this code it become with fixed size [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHojP.jpg)

and if i tried fix it, page loooks something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/va6sJ.png)

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}

.main-body{
    background: deepskyblue;
    bottom: 0;
}

.main-line{
    background: aliceblue;
}
.footer{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have body and main body?

This would be right:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
body { background-color: deepskyblue; }
```